# How to get parent id of root for children in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's what I have (table's name is `pobjects`):

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
| id | title      | user_id | published | uri  | type_id | parent_id |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | file1.bpmn |       1 |         0 | NULL |       1 |      NULL |
|  2 | file2.bpmn |       1 |         0 | NULL |       1 |      NULL |
|  3 | file3.bpmn |       1 |         0 | NULL |       1 |      NULL |
|  4 | file4.bpmn |       2 |         0 | NULL |       1 |      NULL |
|  5 | root       |       1 |         0 | NULL |       2 |      NULL |
|  6 | root       |       2 |         0 | NULL |       2 |      NULL |
|  7 | root       |       3 |         0 | NULL |       2 |      NULL |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
```

These rows represent files and root directories. I need to update each file's `parent_id` to the same user's root directory `id`. So, basically I need this result:

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
| id | title      | user_id | published | uri  | type_id | parent_id |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | file1.bpmn |       1 |         0 | NULL |       1 |         5 |
|  2 | file2.bpmn |       1 |         0 | NULL |       1 |         5 |
|  3 | file3.bpmn |       1 |         0 | NULL |       1 |         5 |
|  4 | file4.bpmn |       2 |         0 | NULL |       1 |         6 |
|  5 | root       |       1 |         0 | NULL |       2 |      NULL |
|  6 | root       |       2 |         0 | NULL |       2 |      NULL |
|  7 | root       |       3 |         0 | NULL |       2 |      NULL |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------+-----------+
```

Help would be much obliged as I'm not an SQL guru but I'm tired of not using the possibilities of SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`UPDATE .. JOIN`](http://www.voidtricks.com/mysql-inner-join-update/) :

```
UPDATE YourTable t
JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.user_id = s.user_id and t.title <> 'root' and s.title = 'root')
SET t.parent_id = s.id
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes as it won't let me accept it so soon.

Comment: No problem mate :).